# Implementing Google Site Search results on a different page from the search bar

Tags: javascript

I have created the search bar ok

```
<div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '003731665015056279148:yerke0wpj1y';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="http://www.mysite.com/search-results.php"></gcse:searchbox-only>

</div>
```

This seems to work fine, it redirects to the search-results.php page and contains "?q=search query" in the url.

My results page contains

```
<div id="searchbox-only">
</div>
```

I am guessing there should be some code in the div here, but can't work out what.

Also is it possible to add any CSS to the search bar and results?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the example I have in setting up CSE your result page should have a piece of code something like this:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'your CSE id goes here';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

However, I am having difficulties getting it to display on a separate page...